# I have error of unexpected symbol in ellipse fuction. I tried to draw ellipse using ellipse pakage

Tags: ellipse, drawellipse

ellipse  fuction (hlaxa=1,hlaxb=1,theta=0, xc=0,yc=0,newplot=TRUE,npoint=100)                           {                                                                                                       a<- seq(0,2*pi,length=npoints+1)                                                                       x<- hlaxa*cos(a)                                                                                       y<- hlaxb*sin(a)                                                                                    alpha<- pi/3                                                                                          rad<- sqrt(x^2+y^2)                                                                                    xp<- rad*cos(alpha+theta)+xc                                                                           yp<- rad*sin(alpha+theta)+yc                                                                    if(newplot)                                                                          plot(xp,yp,type="1",...)                                                                               else lines(xp,yp,...)                                                                            invisible()                                                                                              }

I tried to draw ellipse using ellipse package but it did't work. it say unexpected symbol in ellipse fuction.

ellipse                                                                        fuction (hlaxa=1,hlaxb=1,theta=0, xc=0,yc=0,newplot=TRUE,npoint=100)                  {                                                                               a<- seq(0,2*pi,length=npoints+1)                                           x<- hlaxa*cos(a)                                                             y<- hlaxb*sin(a)                                                             alpha<- pi/3                                                                 rad<- sqrt(x^2+y^2)                                                          xp<- rad*cos(alpha+theta)+xc                                                 yp<- rad*sin(alpha+theta)+yc                                                 if(newplot)                                                                     plot(xp,yp,type="1",...)                                                         else lines(xp,yp,...)                                                        invisible()                                                               }

it happen in such ways.